How the Baretto Naehrig rules for computing a sextic extension having the exact same order as the prime curve were computed?
For example, EIP197, I have $Y^2 = X^3 + 3$ having order $q$ equal to
21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495617
It’s the altbn128 curve over the prime field 21888242871839275222246405745257275088696311157297823662689037894645226208583
Now I have the degree 2 extension’s of the prime curve : $Y^2 = X^3 + 3 (i+9)^{-1}$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_p^2 = \mathbb{F}_p[i]/(i^2+1)$ instead of the prime field. It has the same prime order as the prime curve. My question is

Such curve parameters where computed from the rules etablished for Baretto Naehrig curves but how such rules were created ?


In my knowledge an extend curve will never have the same order.

@KnuckBalls then in addition to https://www.cryptojedi.org/papers/pfcpo.pdf you have a counterexample in the question !
